# Is there a wireless double-earred earpiece for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, peripheral

Is there such a thing as a double wireless earpiece for iPhone 4?

I've just bought a wireless earpiece and argh! it's only single ear. I didn't expect that, I mean I didn't even know that anyone would ever sell single ear earpiece.

So basically before I go back to the shop and request for an exchange I'd just like to confirm is there even such a thing as a wireless double-earpiece for iPhone 4? (because I don't actually trust what they have to say)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about a [bluetooth headset](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=bluetooth%20headset&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)? To my knowledge, they are predominantly single ear because they are meant to substitute putting a phone up to your ear.

However, there does exist bluetooth stereo headsets that can handle music and make calls using their built in microphone. They aren't nearly as compact however, and likely not as battery efficient.

Take a look at the [Plantronics BackBeat 906 Stereo Bluetooth Headphones Set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TK3ACA) if that is what you are in the market for.

Do give the guys at the store a break when you return the product. You are a rarity to request a stereo headset as 99% sold in stores today are single ear piece units.

Comment: I have a stereo bluetooth headset for biking. Tired of getting the cord snagged. Sound quality can be a little iffy, and I still use the single ear for talking on the phone.

Comment: ic, so basically that thing is not for listening to music ? btw does stereo  mean "there is 2 earpiece" or does it mean "it is for music" ?

Comment: i don't need the mouthpiece. i only want it for music (quality)

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, stereo means "two." Mono means "one." If you are looking for a pair of wireless headphones to exclusive play music, then you would be wanting to get one that has a receiver that can connect to a mini-headphone jack (like the iPhone and most handheld devices). There exists wireless headphones that connect via a USB dongle, so make sure you get one like the Plantronics above (you can see it has a Bluetooth adapter that fits into the 3.5 mm jack found on your iPhone).

Comment: @cksum heys cool, I didn't manage to get a refund in the end. Btw are you aware if I could connect the mono one to play music? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26567/6533

Comment: Oh yea I couldn't tell from the picture at http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001TK3ACA/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 but is the "middle part" separable? (having just the 2 ears)

Comment: @Pacerier Technically you can pump out music to an ear piece but whether the functionality has been brought to your device is another matter. It's unlikely you can do it without jailbreaking. I'm not aware if anyone has released any such app. And if they have, they'll have to support your specific ear piece. As for your second question, I would say no. The bar looks attached to each ear piece.

Comment: I have a pair of the Sennheiser MM 404 earphones, and I like them a LOT.  A friend has some Motorola earphones that are less expensive, and another friend has the Beats Wireless On-Ear Headphones—which *he* likes.  In short, get some Bluetooth stereo earphones and don't look back.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Motorola S305. Actually I've had 5 of them, i love them and I've simply worn them out. I've logged thousands of hours listening to them. It goes for about $30 on Amazon.