# Connecting headset to iPhone's iPod player

Tags: iphone, music

I have a [Plantronics ML10](http://www.plantronics.com/au/product/ml10) headset and after setting it up through bluetooth it can handle calls. But when I play music with my IPhone, the sound is not coming through the earpiece.

Is there anyway I could "channel" the sound to the earpiece whenever I play songs with the iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think it will work. To send music over Bluetooth, the device needs to support the *A2DP* Bluetooth profile. Your headset (and most others not specifically intended for music) only supports the basic handsfree profile, so the iPhone can't send it music from the iPod app.